# colMeans of successive lines in a matrix in R

Tags: r, mean, lines

I have a matrix of 30 rows:

```
set.seed(1234)
m = matrix(rnorm(300), 0)
```

I want to calculate the colMeans of each five successive lines. 
For example:

colMeans of rows 1,2,3,4,5

colMeans of rows 2,3,4,5,6

colMeans of rows 3,4,5,6,7

...

colMeans of rows 16,17,18,19,20

How I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

Functions from the package `zoo` can be useful here. Try

```
set.seed(1234)
m = matrix(rnorm(300), nrow = 30)
zoo::rollmean(m, 5) # option 1
zoo::rollapply(m, 5, mean) # option 2
```